# Angular can't make my function get called

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an angular code that tries to hide columns of my table using `shouldHideColumn()` function. It seems that whatever I do, I am not able to bind my tags to the  and . It gives an error saying `Can't bind to 'printerColumns' since it isn't a known property of 'th'`. At this state I have added logs to my `shouldHideColumn()` function to debug it but it won't get called anyway. Console has nothing. Let me provide the code here. There may be many things wrong with the code. After getting the `shouldHideColumn()` to work, I need to see if it successfully hides table header `<th>` tags as well as `<td>`s.

**URL of Stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b9k382?file=src/my-component.component.ts

This shows nothing since it uses index.html but I am tagging `<app-my-component></app-my-component>` so I bootstrapped `myComponent` to it so I expect my table to be shown since my `shouldHideColumn()` function doesn't work.

I provided a snippet but I am not really sure how I post separate files, so I am only providing my hide-column.directive.ts file as javascript file. Rest of the files are below:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HideColumnDirective } from './hide-column.directive';
import { MyComponent } from './my-component.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HideColumnDirective, MyComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  bootstrap: [MyComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Apart from this I have also a my-component.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./global_styles.css'],
})
export class MyComponent {
  printerColumns = ['Brand', 'Model'];

  constructor() {}
}
```

For those that cannot access to URL I provided;

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: 'th[appHideColumn], td[appHideColumn]' })
export class HideColumnDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() appHideColumn: string = '';
  @Input() printerColumns: string[] = [];

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.shouldHideColumn()) {
      this.el.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

  shouldHideColumn() {
    console.log("come'ere");
    console.log('appHideColumn:', this.appHideColumn);
    console.log(
      'shouldHide:',
      this.printerColumns.indexOf(this.appHideColumn) > -1
    );
    return this.printerColumns.indexOf(this.appHideColumn) > -1;
  }
}
```

```css
.table-container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

thead {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th appHideColumn="'Brand'" [printerColumns]="printerColumns">Brand</th>
        <th [appHideColumn]="'Model'" [printerColumns]="printerColumns">
          Model
        </th>
        <th [appHideColumn]="'Price'" [printerColumns]="printerColumns">
          Price
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td [appHideColumn]="'Brand'" [printerColumns]="printerColumns">HP</td>
        <td [appHideColumn]="'Model'" [printerColumns]="printerColumns">
          OfficeJet Pro 9015e
        </td>
        <td [appHideColumn]="'Price'" [printerColumns]="printerColumns">
          $229.99
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td [appHideColumn]="'Brand'" [printerColumns]="printerColumns">
          SONY
        </td>
        <td [appHideColumn]="'Model'" [printerColumns]="printerColumns">
          SUperMultiDuper
        </td>
        <td [appHideColumn]="'Price'" [printerColumns]="printerColumns">
          $2229.99
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td [appHideColumn]="'Brand'" [printerColumns]="printerColumns">
          Canon
        </td>
        <td [appHideColumn]="'Model'" [printerColumns]="printerColumns">
          PIXMA TR8520
        </td>
        <td [appHideColumn]="'Price'" [printerColumns]="printerColumns">
          $179.99
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read [ask], where it notes "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so — **but also copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/) to make a live demo of inline JavaScript/HTML/CSS."

Comment: Where is your appmodule ?

Comment: my appmodule is my main.ts, I guess

Comment: @HereticMonkey I edited my question so that there is a minimal code in the snippet and rest of it is in the question itself.

Comment: @Karavana please take a look here: https://angular-rxmtcd.stackblitz.io - it's your project with a fix and works as expected. Notice that you missed the enclosing `[]` in your first `<th>` element.

Comment: @Karavana See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxmtcd?file=src/my-component.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you bootstrapped your `MyComponent`  in App Module but you didn't bootstrap the App module which generally part of main.ts like `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)`

Here is the working example of your Stackblitz link :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-euctyc?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: After adding the missing the enclosing [] in the first <th> element like @Benny pointed out in the comments, this works!